# XSLT – creating a numbered attribute based on the value of another attribute

Tags: xslt

From a document such as the following list:

```
<list>
    <city ref="Paris">Paris</city>
    <city ref="Rome">Rome</city>
    <city ref="NYC">New York</city>
    <city ref="Lisboa">Lisboa</city>
    <city ref="Lisboa">Lisbon</city>
    <city ref="Lisboa">Lisbonne</city>
    <city ref="NYC">The Big Apple</city>
</list>
```

I would like to obtain a copy of this list, with an added numeric attribute derived from the @ref attribute (ideally in alphabetical order), for an output like:

```
<list>
    <city ref="Paris" id="3">Paris</city>
    <city ref="Rome" id="4">Rome</city>
    <city ref="NYC" id="2">New York</city>
    <city ref="Lisboa" id="1">Lisboa</city>
    <city ref="Lisboa" id="1">Lisbon</city>
    <city ref="Lisboa" id="1">Lisbonne</city>
    <city ref="NYC" id="2">The Big Apple</city>
</list>
```

I suppose there is a way to use `<xsl:key>` to number a sorted list of my @ref attributes, but am not fluent enough to get there.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XSLT 3.0 (as supported by Saxon 9.7) it is as easy as

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:variable name="cities" select="sort(distinct-values(/list/city/@ref))"/>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:template match="city/@ref">
        <xsl:copy/>
        <xsl:attribute name="id" select="index-of($cities, .)"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With XSLT 2.0 we can use

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:variable name="cities" as="xs:string*">
        <xsl:perform-sort select="distinct-values(/list/city/@ref)">
            <xsl:sort select="."/>
        </xsl:perform-sort>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="city/@ref">
        <xsl:copy/>
        <xsl:attribute name="id" select="index-of($cities, .)"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Finally with XSLT 1.0 the above "translates" into

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    exclude-result-prefixes="exsl"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:key name="city" match="city" use="@ref"/>

    <xsl:variable name="cities-rtf">
        <xsl:for-each select="/list/city[generate-id() = generate-id(key('city', @ref)[1])]">
            <xsl:sort select="@ref"/>
            <city id="{position()}" ref="{@ref}"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="cities" select="exsl:node-set($cities-rtf)/city"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="city/@ref">
        <xsl:copy/>
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:value-of select="$cities[@ref = current()]/@id"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Out of curiosity, would there be any practicable alternative with XSLT 2.0?

Comment: Thank you so much!